# did i make a command through a dialog in mirc?

Tags: scripting, dialog, mirc

i've created a dialog that allows to kick an user. this dialog has a textbox where the user must write the name of the one to kick and then press the OK button to kick. I created all the dialog but i don't understand how to give the command on the ok.
somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a `sclick` event for that dialog:

```
on *:dialog:DIALOG_NAME:sclick:BUTTON_ID:{
    ; PSEUDO: get contents of textbox
    ; PSEUDO: kick user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use /kick $active $$?="Enter user to kick:" you can also use the $input() identifier.